# Python Selenium Check if .click() was clickable or not

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I would like to use an if function that tells me whether a button has been clicked or not in my code given below, if yes then "a" should be output if no then "b".

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "css-xf3ahq", " " ))][text()="Button"]')
element.click()

if element == True:
    print("a")

else:
    print("b")
```

up to now b has always been written although the button is clickable

Comment: If you use `print(element)` you will see that it does not equal `True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try:
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "css-xf3ahq", " " ))][text()="Button"]')
    element.click()
    print('Clickable')
except:
    print('Not clickable')
```

Just try to click on it otherwise print error if it isn't. You can check for presence with a webdriver and handle different errors with multiple excepts if you want. Not sure if you can do it with an if here.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has: element_to_be_clickable() which may be a better solution to what you're trying to do. i.e.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "css-xf3ahq", " " ))][text()="Button"]'))
    print('a')

except selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:
    print('b')
```

Comment: It shouldn't wait until the button is clickable, there are several buttons on the side where I want to do this and I just want to check all of them whether they are clickable or not without it stopping

Comment: I don't quite think there's another way to check whether it's clickable or not. Pretty sure this is the only way to tell @Lumpy187

Answer (score 0):

you can use element_to_be_clicked condition

like this:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
)
```

Comment: It shouldn't wait until the button is clickable, there are several buttons on the side where I want to do this and I just want to check all of them whether they are clickable or not without it stopping